# Acumatica Error When Publishing -- But No Code Changes Were Made

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am working on a custom processing screen focused on inventory. My code was using a simple processing statement with InventoryItem as the Data:

```
public PXProcessing<InventorySiteItems> Processing;
```

However, I needed to make a joined data source, so I changed it to:

```
public PXProcessingJoin<InventoryItem, 
 LeftJoin<INItemSite, On<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<INItemSite.inventoryID>>,
 InnerJoin<INLocationStatus, On<INLocationStatus.siteID, Equal<INItemSite.siteID>,
     And<INLocationStatus.inventoryID, Equal<INItemSite.inventoryID>>>>>>   Processing;
```

This all worked. But, In order to do some debugging to check for duplicate records, I went to change my Processing Screen using the customization editor. I wanted to add InventoryID to the columns. InventoryCD was already there, but that I wanted the actual ID, since it is unique.

I made the change, but when I went to publish it, I get this now:

```
Building directory '\WebSiteValidationDomain\App_RuntimeCode\'.
\App_RuntimeCode\SOBackorderProcess.cs(28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'InventoryRawAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
\App_RuntimeCode\SOBackorderProcess.cs(28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'InventoryRaw' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
\App_RuntimeCode\SOBackorderProcess.cs(28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IsKey' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
\App_RuntimeCode\SOBackorderProcess.cs(28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DisplayName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
\App_RuntimeCode\SOBackorderProcess.cs(28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'InventoryRawAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Compiler time, in seconds: 8.4989854
```

I tried to back the change out, but the errors stay.

I double checked in the AcumaticaERP\Pages\PS directory, and the ASP file is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/ListView.master" AutoEventWireup="true" ValidateRequest="false" CodeFile="PS501000.aspx.cs" Inherits="Page_PS501000" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/ListView.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="cont1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phDS" Runat="Server">
    <px:PXDataSource ID="ds" runat="server" Visible="True" Width="100%"
        TypeName="Plyler.SOBackorderProcess"
        PrimaryView="Processing"
        >
        <CallbackCommands>

        </CallbackCommands>
    </px:PXDataSource>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="cont2" ContentPlaceHolderID="phL" runat="Server">
    <px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Width="100%" Height="150px" SkinID="Primary" AllowAutoHide="false">
        <Levels>
            <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="Processing">
                <Columns>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Selected" Width="60" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="InventoryCD" Width="70" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Descr" Width="280" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="INItemSite__SiteID" Width="140" />
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="INLocationStatus__QtyOnHand" Width="100" />
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="INLocationStatus__QtyAvail" Width="100" />
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Availability" Width="70" ></px:PXGridColumn></Columns>
            </px:PXGridLevel>
        </Levels>
        <AutoSize Container="Window" Enabled="True" MinHeight="150" />
        <ActionBar >
        </ActionBar>
    </px:PXGrid>
</asp:Content>
```

All of this has been published, compiling, and running just fine for the past several days. But as soon as I added that field, now I cannot get it to publish -- even though I backed the change out.

I saw an old post about an issue with permissions, where it was suggested adding:

```
<add key="aspnet:DisableAppPathModifier" value="false" />
```

To the web config file under  -- and I have done that with no change.

What could have changed that now causes this issue?

[EDIT]
I NEVER call InventoryRaw in my source code:
[image: Search Results]
Here is Line 28 of SOBackorderProcess.CS:

[image: Screenshot of VS Studio]

Here it is with the snippet added (with no change in behavior, sadly)
[image: Screenshot of edited code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trace points to source code file:
App_RuntimeCode\SOBackorderProcess.cs

You have 5 unreferenced types on line 28 on Inventory attribute:
InventoryRawAttribute
InventoryRaw
IsKey
DisplayName

You need to add `using` namespace directive in source code file or fully qualify the types with namespace.

Example:

```
using PX.Objects.IN;
[InventoryRaw]

[PX.Objects.IN.InventoryRaw]
```

**EDIT:**

To remove lingering files deployed to App_RuntimeCode folder.
First check if there are source code files on the web server file system in the target IIS virtual directory under App_RuntimeCode folder.

Then for each tenant of the Acumatica website, check for customization items deployed from Code and Data Access section.

[image]

Comment: Except never in my code (i.e. SOBackorderProcess.cs) do I ever reference InventoryRaw. And line 28 of the code is none of those things. Where should I add the snippet you showed? I already had PX.Objects.IN in my using statements. When I added your code snippet at the class, it changes nothing. I get the same error... (See addition to my question)

Comment: Are you checking the file inside 'app_runtimecode' folder?

Comment: If the file is not there, then it is inside the customization project editor. I can't tell which file you are looking at inside visual studio.

Comment: Actually I see that it's inside visual studio project Plyler.csproj. That is not the correct file you are looking at. Check inside 'app_runtimecode' folder and in customization Code and Data Access Class section. Not in the unrelated visual studio project.

Comment: There is no SOBackorderProcess.cs in app_runtimecode. The only thing in there is a file:  folder.runtime with 0 bytes. I went to the Root of the AcumaticaERP project and used search -- there is no SOBackOrderProcess.cs anywhere. (Except in my VS Project, of course) I also manually went into the Customization folder. It is not there.

Comment: I looked at other projects I have done, and I see that there are CS files in those. So, somehow when creating and then backing out the change to the Process Screen, that file must have been lost. Is there a way of recreating it without starting over?

Comment: If it's not in APP_RuntimeCode folder check in all tenants for a customization which has SOBackOrderProcess in DAC or CODE section. The file is somewhere, otherwise you wouldn't have the error. As a last recourse you can execute IISReset but that won't resolve the issue if the file is still being published.

Comment: Compiled libraries (DLL) go into Bin folder so that SOBackOrderProcess file is not from your visual studio project. Code and Data Access Class items in customization project are the ones which end up in App_RuntimeCode folder.

Comment: I discovered where it was. Apparently, when I had tried to add the InventoryID field to my Process Screen, it created something in the CODE section. The publish must have been looking in there, trying to apply it, and having issues at that time. I created a new extension library, bound the project to that library, and commented the code out, and then moved the code to the extension library -- all of which PROBABLY wasn't needed. I think I could have just cleared the code and saved it, but I wanted to make sure it was gone. After that, it published fine.

Comment: It could have originated from the customization Inspect Element feature. When you click on actions in that dialog like customize business logic it will create code files.